# Videos to be downloaded

Tags: facebook, user-interface

I would love to ask the Help page this question but I cannot find where I can submit a question.  I only see "frequently asked questions". Anyway, dear Facebook gurus,  how can I download my videos back off of Facebook.  I have some I want to save and I cannot figure out how to retrieve them. Very important.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this website](http://www.facebookvideodown.com/) to download Facebook videos.

But then I found [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/97964).
Install it and you can download videos right off from Facebook. No need to copy and past URLs anywhere. Pretty handy.

Answer (score -1):

Give this resource a try: http://www.downfacebook.com/

I have not tested it yet but it looks promising.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below link to download your Facebook videos:
[Facebook Video Downloader](http://www.facebookvideodownloader.us/)
[Facebook Private Video Downloader](http://www.facebookvideodownloader.us/private-downloader.php)

By using the above tool you can also download Facebook private videos. This is the tool I been using since a long time without any issues.